# wso2CEP on docker - supports JMS (activemq) and other clients

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-cep

I'm using a docker image of wso2CEP. 
I want to Event Receiver and Publisher that will connect to JMS (ActiveMQ)
and in the future maybe other clients (Kafka) or cassandra or http.

How can I add this support to dockerized CEP? I dont want to rebuild the image 
with the needed jars. is there a different way to provide it?

thank you
tomer

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can copy the jars to the running container and [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#commit-a-container-with-new-configurations) to create a new image with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Docker volume to copy the files to the running container, even directly mounting the volume to `CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/eventreceivers/`.

You can even mount the volume to `CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/`, package the event receivers, publishers, streams etc as a Carbon Archive, and copy the resulting `.car` file to the volume so that Carbon itself would take care of undeploying and redeploying the new artifacts.

However the best approach would be to actually rebuild the images when the artifacts get updated. Containerization, especially with Docker, encourages immutability of the servers and the deployment should be updated with a new Docker image rather than modifying existing containers. If the frequency at which these artifacts get updated is not unmanageably high, I would always suggest to follow Docker image building approach.